# "Skipped 76 frames" en Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, c#, .net, xamarin

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Xamarin.Android en la que uso el `Media Plugin` para capturar una foto y enviarla como parámetro a otro `Activity`, pero al tomar la foto y darle OK, hay un momento en el que se muestra una pantalla como esta:

[image: Pantalla en blanco]

Y en el logcat aparece:

> > skipped 76 frames the application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Cómo solucionarlo? No considero que el código que estoy utilizando haga un trabajo muy pesado, ¿o me equivoco? El método es el siguiente:

```
private async void TakePhotoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, 
                "La cámara no está disponible", 
                ToastLength.Long).Show();
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions()
    {
        DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
        SaveToAlbum = false
    });

    if (file == null)
        return;

    Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(ResultActivity));
    i.PutExtra("Image", file.Path);
    StartActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Esto no te esta causando problema en la ejecución de tu aplicación cierto? =)

Comment: hey Javier, bienvenido a SOes :D de casualidad lo estás ejecutando en un dispositivo o en un emulador?

Comment: Intenta habilitando la aceleración por hardware mediante tu manifest-xml en <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>

Comment: @fredyfx es interesante probar lo que comentas, eso también podría evitar los mensajes.

Comment: @fredyfx Estoy ejecutándolo en un dispositivo (LG G4 Marshmallow). Probaré con tu idea! :D

Comment: @fredyfx Pues nada :(. Estoy pensando que es por el plugin (tal vez por el await), ya que cuando uso la forma nativa de capturar imágenes no pasa eso.

Comment: @JavierEscobarEspinoza ni modo hermano, al menos sabemos que eso de agregar la aceleración por hardware no resultó :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joven, y si hace lo siguiente, digo :D!

[image: Java Max Heap Size 1G]

Comment: Funcionó! Ya había olvidado esa variable de entorno :D

Answer (score 0):

Javier, estos mensajes son desplegados en la consola usando Xamarin o Android Studio, hasta cierto punto esto probablemente no este causando un problema en la ejecución de tu aplicación, pero te doy dos causas importantes que ocasionan el despliegue de estos mensajes.

- Una causa es que los recursos o media que intenta cargar tu aplicación son "pesados".
- Asegura que tu proceso se esta ejecutando fuera del hilo principal ([Main Thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html))

Comment: La aplicación funciona correctamente, pero esa transición entre `activities` es lo que no se ve muy bien.